# matching the ids from different data frame and arranging the column values in to a single data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 dataframes like below,

` df1=[ 1q2 123
        1q3 212
      1d4 234...]

df2=[ 1q1 223
      1q2 126
      1q3 42
      1d4 314...]
df3=[ 1q2 923
      1q4 121
      1d3 423...] `

How can I get result like
`dfans=[1q1 0  223   0

      1q2 123 126  923
      1q3 212 42   423
      1d4 234 314  121....]`

column1 contains the id column 2  get the correct value for id's  after matching ids,from df1;
similarly values matched from df2 in column 3 and value matching from df3.
if no values for that id is available place a 0 in that location.
is there any way?

Comment: If you write a python program, you can get that. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a simple merge.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E'], 'var1' : [1, 2, 5, 8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'var2' : [1, 3, 8, 8]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'var3' : [2, 4, 6, 7]})

dfAns = df1.merge(df2, on = 'id', how = 'outer').merge(df3, on='id', how='outer').fillna(0)
```

The output will look like  -

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aritesh, i did concat but Nan was filling in the blank space.